# Is transaction amount inclusive of transaction_fee?

Tags: coinbase-api

For the transaction resource type (https://developers.coinbase.com/api/v2#transactions), is the on-chain transaction fee (transaction_fee) included in the amount/native_amount?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've confirmed with my own transactions the native_amount does include the Coinbase Fee.